# how to install the mounting bracket for ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan, mounting

[image]I need to install a ceiling fan, but when I looked at the fan box to hang the mounting bracket, I cannot find the screw to hang it.
[image]

i have a metal mounting bracket which I like to screw to attached to fan box[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What was there before? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Can you get us a photo of the inside of that box that doesn't have the translucent-ish plastic thing in the way?

Comment: I have added the picture by removing the plastic thing

Comment: you cannot hang a fan on the plastic bracket that is in the picture

Comment: @jsotola i have a metal mounting bracket where I need to hang to fan box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be threaded holes for attaching screws in the red circled spots.

The one on the right seems to have a semi-circular notch from a previously installed screw.

[image]

edit:

Internet search reveals that the box is made by Arlington Industries.

http://www.aifittings.com/catalog/fan-fixture-boxes/

The markings on the box in the picture mean `remove the screw and use in the red circled area`

Comment: i am not finding any threaded holes for screw.. it means do I need to drill it..?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance

Comment: Did you get the mounting bracket fixed by drilling at the places indicated by red circle and using screws which were on the box?

Comment: Use the supplied screws, which install directly into the beam/joist (at locations indicated with red circles. Pre-drill if you like or use a #3 Phillips bit with impact gun.

Answer (score 1):

### The mounting screws and instructions you're looking for are staring you in the face

The fan bracket screws that go with the Arlington FB442 one-sided saddle box are pre-provisioned in the box, next to where the cable in your photo exits.  (You've started to back one out already, even.)  Once you have them out, you should be able to use them to screw the metal bracket that came with your fan into the two "pockets" just outside the sidewalls of the box that are pointed out by the arrows on the box that say "REMOVE SCREW, USE HERE", thus attaching the bracket to the same ceiling joist the fan box is mounted to.

Comment: I am not finding any threaded holes for screw.. it means do I need to drill it..? i can't use any existing pockets to fit it?

Comment: @vinothkumarArumugam -- the trick is that the pockets are places where the box *isn't*...you're driving a wood screw through the hole in the bracket *straight into the joist*, bypassing the box in the process

Comment: Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 1):

While [@ThreePhaseEel's post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/195108/14870) does address your question, I wanted to provide additional images and documentation:

[This is a spec sheet for the FB442 mount](https://www.suppliesdepot.com/images/product-detail/ARLINGE00335_1_2.pdf) (also FB443 and FB444) shown in your picture. I've taken a screenshot of relevant portion of the flyer and added it here:

[image: Arlington FB442 Mount]

[This city-data forum thread](https://www.city-data.com/forum/house/3030278-ceiling-fan-install-help-please.html) from 2019 references the same fan mount. The users in this thread refer to mount as both a "half-saddle" and a "direct mount saddle box".

Simply put, you run the screws for the ceiling fan bracket directly into the joist and this "mount" seems more like a junction box to contain your electrical wires. As shown on the face of the FB442 it indicates where to run the included screws in order to mount your ceiling fan.

I think it's a little annoying that I'll be removing / replacing wood screws directly in my joist every time I want to change the fan bracket, but hopefully that won't have to happen too many times while I live in my current home. Oh well.

I hope this post proves to be useful to others who are searching for the same information you were (I came here looking as well).